# Reading XML File/Manifest from Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am learning Powershell these days so bear with me please. I am trying to read the following XML manifest with PowerShell:

```xml
<manifest desc="sql manifest">
  <projects>
    <project project_directory="$/TFS/Main/branch/">
      <files>
        <file filename="Shrink.sql"/>
        <file filename="Users.sql"/>
      </files>
    </project>
    <project project_directory="$/TFS/Main/branch/Pre/">
      <files>
        <file filename="Logins.sql"/>
      </files>
    </project>
    <project project_directory="$/TFS/Main/branch/Post/">
      <files>
        <file filename="Security.sql"/>
      </files>
    </project>
  </projects>
</manifest>
```

I am expecting results like this:

```
$/TFS/Main/branch/Shrink.sql
$/TFS/Main/branch/Users.sql
$/TFS/Main/branch/Pre/Logins.sql
$/TFS/Main/branch/Post/Security.sql
```

Can you guys help me with PowerShell script?

```bsh
$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "xmlfile.xml"
```

Comment: Have you done some basic Googling for topics like "How do you parse XML files in PowerShell"?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the ** characters, the following code should return the results you want, assuming you're running the command from the same directory as the xml file:

```
#### More than one directory
$results = @()

[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml

$directoryCount = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project.Count
$directoryNames = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project.project_directory

for($i = 0 ; $i -lt $directoryCount; $i++)
{
    $files = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project[$i].files.file

    foreach($file in $files.filename)
    {
        $results += $directoryNames[$i] + $file
    }
}

return $results

#### Single Directory
$results = @()

[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml

$directoryCount = @($XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project).Count
$directoryNames = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project.project_directory

for($i = 0 ; $i -lt $directoryCount; $i++)
{
    $files = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project.files.file

    foreach($file in $files.filename)
    {
        $results += $directoryNames + $file
    }
}

return $results
```

If desirable, you could put this into functions to eliminate some code duplication and create a reusable script:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Gets XML file to parse and displays results
.DESCRIPTION
   Reads content of an XML file, parses the
   manifest.projects.project.project_directory
   tag and displays concatenated results of 
   project.project_directory and child file.filename
   items
.EXAMPLE
   \Get-XMLFileItems -XMLFilePath "C:\users\myusername\desktop\myxmlfile.xml"
.EXAMPLE
   .\Get-XMLFileItems -XMLFilePath "C:\users\myusername\desktop\myxmlfile.xml" -MultipleDirectories $False
#>

[cmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [string]$XMLFilePath,

    [Parameter()]
    [bool]$MultipleDirectories = $true
)

BEGIN
{
    Function Load-XMLFile
    {
        try
        {
            Write-Output "Loading XML file...`n"
            [xml]$XMLDocument = Get-Content $XMLFilePath

            Get-XMLDirectoryInfo -File $XMLDocument

        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            Write-Error -Message "Error loading XML file $XMLFilePath"
        } 
    }

    Function Get-XMLDirectoryInfo($File)
    {
        try
        {
            $directoryCount = @($File.manifest.projects.project).Count
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            Write-Error "Unable to count 'manifest.projects.project' in schema"
        }  

        try
        {
            $directoryNames = $File.manifest.projects.project.project_directory
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            Write-Error "Unable to find names for items in 'manifest.projects.project.project_directory' in schema"
        }

        Get-FilesInXMLSchema -File $File
    }

    Function Get-FilesInXMLSchema($File)
    {
        for($i = 0 ; $i -lt $directoryCount; $i++)
        {
            if($MultipleDirectories -eq $true)
            {
                $files = $File.manifest.projects.project[$i].files.file

                foreach($item in $files.filename)
                {
                    [array]$results += $directoryNames[$i] + $item
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $files = $XmlDocument.manifest.projects.project.files.file

                foreach($item in $files.filename)
                {
                    [array]$results += $directoryNames + $item
                } 
            }
        }

        Show-Results -InputObject $results
    }

    Function Show-Results($InputObject)
    {
        try
        {
            return $InputObject
        }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            Write-Error -Message "Error displaying results"
        }
    }

    Function Write-Error($Message)
    {
        Write-Output $Message
        $Error[0]
        Write-Output "Exiting script"
        Exit
    }
}

PROCESS
{
    Load-XMLFile
}

END
{}
```

If you don't specify the -MultipleDirectories parameter it will default to $true. Check the help comments at the beginning for usage. I tested this against both your XML examples and it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you this work perfectly if I have more than one count on the directory. It does not seems to be working for one directory only:

<manifest desc="sql manifest">
  <projects>
    <project project_directory="$/TFS/Main/branch/">
      <files>
        <file filename="Shrink.sql"/>
      </files>
    </project>

  </projects>
</manifest>



Any suggestions?

Comment: Robin, I updated my response to include approaches to both scenarios, and a script using an advanced function that you could reuse against files with the same XML schema. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Thank you user2734259. This works. I will create function and let main script call this.